# Get all Instagram feeds using londatiga library

Tags: android, instagram

I am currently working on a Social Media Application, I want to get all Instagram pictures feeds. I am using the londatiga library, so far I am getting only 10 feeds and I want to get all, code I am using is:

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

    protected void onCancelled() {
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Feeds...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        long result = 0;

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("count", "10"));

            InstagramRequest request = new InstagramRequest(
                    mInstagramSession.getAccessToken());
            String response = request.createRequest("GET",
                    "/users/self/feed", params);

            if (!response.equals("")) {
                JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response)
                        .nextValue();
                JSONArray jsonData = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

                int length = jsonData.length();
                flag_loading = false;

                if (length > 0) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonPhoto = jsonData.getJSONObject(i)
                                .getJSONObject("images")
                                .getJSONObject("low_resolution");
                        mPhotoList.add(jsonPhoto.getString("url"));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private LinkedList<String> mPhotoList = new LinkedList<String>();
    private LinkedList<String> mPhotoListIds = new LinkedList<String>();

    private static String nextMaxId = "";
    private static String url = "";

    //onCreateView


        listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount != 0) {
                    if (flag_loading == false) {
                        flag_loading = true;
                        new DownloadTask(true).execute();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        if (mInstagramSession.isActive()) {
            new DownloadTask(false).execute();
        }





    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

        private boolean isBeingPaginated = false;

        public DownloadTask(boolean isBeingPaginated) {
            this.isBeingPaginated = isBeingPaginated;
        }

        protected void onCancelled() {

        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Feeds...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            long result = 0;


            try {
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>(1);
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("count", "10"));


                if (isBeingPaginated) {
                    url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/self/media/recent?access_token=" + mInstagramSession.getAccessToken() + "&max_id=" + nextMaxId;

                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("next_url", url));
                }

                InstagramRequest request = new InstagramRequest(
                        mInstagramSession.getAccessToken());
                String response = request.createRequest("GET",
                        "/users/self/feed", params);

                if (!response.equals("")) {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response)
                            .nextValue();
                    JSONArray jsonData = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
                    JSONObject jsonPaginatioNData = jsonObj.getJSONObject("pagination");

                    //Fetching nextMaxId
                    if (jsonPaginatioNData.length() > 0) {
                        //JSONObject paginationJsonObject = jsonPaginatioNData.getJSONObject(0);
                        nextMaxId = jsonPaginatioNData.getString("next_max_id");
                        Log.d("max", nextMaxId);
                        isBeingPaginated = true;

                    }

                    int length = jsonData.length();
                    flag_loading = false;

                    if (length > 0) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonPhoto = jsonData.getJSONObject(i)
                                    .getJSONObject("images")
                                    .getJSONObject("low_resolution");
                            JSONObject jsonUser = jsonData.getJSONObject(i)
                                    .getJSONObject("users_in_photo")
                                    .getJSONObject("user");

                            String jsonPhotoIds = jsonData.getJSONObject(i)
                                    .getString("id");
                            String jsonPhotoIds = jsonData.getJSONObject(i)
                                    .getString("id");
                            Log.d("ID: ", jsonPhotoIds);

                            mPhotoList.addjsonPhoto.getString("url")
                            mPhotoListIds.add(jsonPhotoIds);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

This is what I done, and Now I am getting new feeds on Listview scroll